# Testing whether there is a statistical significance difference between % of ethnic minority students registered in two years at a college

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I would like to test whether there is a statistically significant difference between % of ethnic minority students registered in 2018/19 (before the pandemic) and 2021/2022 (after) at a college.

I have the actual numbers as well. I am mindful that they are not samples but actual proportions (hence my confusion).

Can anyone help in suggesting a suitable test?

Comment: If your null hypothesis is that the proportions are the same, then knowing the actual proportions means you can give a definitive yes/no answer without further analysis. Your question of significance comes in when you are looking at questions like the whether the probabilities of people from different ethnic groups applying/being accepted/registering has changed

Comment: There are no tests needed if you really have the whole population.  Statistical tests are about inference from a sample to a population.  

But be sure you really do have the whole population.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I thought, which is why I got a bit confused by the question that was given to me (it has been a while since I have done any statistics and that was in the field of biology). In the past, when I have dealt with similar data (i.e. a complete dataset, rather than a sample) in public health (i.e. looking at age standardised rates of a disease), we calculated the 95% confidence intervals, plotted these on a graph and then looked at overlap (I know this isn't a proper statistical test, but it gives an idea). Thanks for the answer and reassurance!